# MYSQL select query for most frequent product?

Tags: mysql, count, max

I need help in finding out how to display only the most frequent product for each branch.

This applies to each branch in the DB.

PS: This is done in one table (other tables aren't necessary for this performance), and only the two attributes mentioned are required.

Comment: Please do not use mysql. Use **mysqli** or **PDO** instead

Comment: @Sid Where does the OP use PHP here? And yeah, those are libraries of PHP, but I couldn't find MySQLi Server or PDO Server! *Just being Sarcastic*

Answer (score 1):

Based on Sean's DB sample, I've created query, which do the job, but, please, note what the way you're going in your application looks resource expensive. Try thinking about another way to discover most frequent products, not a DB query.

```
SELECT 
    a.branch_id, `branch_product` , COUNT(branch_product) AS cnt , b.mx
FROM 
    branch_products a 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        branch_id, MAX(cnt) AS mx 
     FROM 
        (SELECT branch_id, COUNT(branch_product) AS cnt FROM branch_products GROUP BY branch_id, branch_product ) AS maxes 
     GROUP BY branch_id) b 
ON a.branch_id = b.branch_id
GROUP BY branch_id, branch_product
HAVING cnt=mx
```

Comment: What in the world are you proposing other than a DB query?  If the data is in a database then use a query to pull the data!

Comment: It strongly depends on application architecture. This could be a kind of pre-indexing, memcaching. Even additional table with pre-calculated items count will make this faster. This query, although effective, will be quite slow on large numbers, and it will be quite hard to build something better to calculate values on-fly

Answer (score 0):

Put the count inside a subquery, ORDER BY the count DESC, then outside of that subquery GROUP BY the branch id:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, count(branch_product) AS cou FROM branch_products
    GROUP BY branch_id, branch_product
    ORDER BY cou DESC
) AS ordbycou
GROUP BY branch_id
```

Yields:

```
+-----------+----------------+-----+
| branch_id | branch_product | cou |
+-----------+----------------+-----+
|         1 | trainers       |   3 |
|         2 | suit           |   2 |
|         3 | suit           |   1 |
+-----------+----------------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's a sample table to try the above query with:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `branch_products` (
  `branch_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `branch_product` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `branch_product` (`branch_product`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `branch_products` (`branch_id`, `branch_product`) VALUES
(1, 'trainers'),
(1, 'trainers'),
(1, 'trainers'),
(1, 'tie'),
(1, 'tie'),
(1, 'suit'),
(2, 'suit'),
(2, 'suit'),
(2, 'tie'),
(3, 'suit');
```

Comment: @AvinVarghese Never heard of sqlfiddle, that's a pretty sweet site.  Thanks for sharing the link to it!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. If branchNo 1 has product trainers and tie occur equally as much then the branchNo 1 would have trainers and tie, although in different rows. So BranchNo 1 in one column and product: trainers in the other, again for the tie.

If I haven't explained properly, try using the fiddle you've gave me, and only put in the data where trainers and tie both occur once for branch one. For example:

`(1, 'trainers'), (1, 'tie'),`

The result should yield both of them because they occur equally as much.

Comment: @Martynogea you never stated you need to display multiple products for a branch if the count is equal for the the highest products.  In that case maybe try performing one subquery to find out what the highest count is for every branch then in a second subquery fetch all products that have a count equal to that highest count.